# Triplet problem : Solve it and remove the error

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<malloc.h>
// function called
long long good_triplets (int* arr, int n) {
    int count=0;
    if(1<=n<=100000)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
        {
            if((((arr[i]+arr[i+1]+arr[i+2])%arr[i  ])==0) &&
               (((arr[i]+arr[i+1]+arr[i+2])%arr[i+1])!=0) && 
               (((arr[i]+arr[i+1]+arr[i+2])%arr[i+2])!=0) )
               count=count + 6;
            if((((arr[i]+arr[i+1]+arr[i+2])%arr[i+1])==0) &&
               (((arr[i]+arr[i+1]+arr[i+2])%arr[i  ])!=0) &&
               (((arr[i]+arr[i+1]+arr[i+2])%arr[i+2])!=0) )
               count=count + 6;
            if((((arr[i]+arr[i+1]+arr[i+2])%arr[i+2])==0) &&
               (((arr[i]+arr[i+1]+arr[i+2])%arr[i+1])!=0) && 
               (((arr[i]+arr[i+1]+arr[i+2])%arr[i])!=0) )
               count=count + 6;
        }
    }
   return count;
}
//main funtion
int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int i_arr;
    int *arr = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for(i_arr=0; i_arr<n; i_arr++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[i_arr]);
    long long out_ = good_triplets(arr, n);
    printf("%lld", out_);
}
```

'remove floating point exception'
'it is a hacker earth que'
'1.Remove floating point exception
2.help quickly please'
QUESTION: why am I getting the Floating Point Exception and how do I fix it?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: Please give more information. What exception occurs under which conditions in which line of your code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I assume that by "que" you do not mean the French "which". Please do not expect too much guessing and spend the effort of writing complete and existing words. Also Asking a question in imperative form is OK for teachers writing an assignment, but seems off here.

Answer (score 0):

`if(1<=n<=100000)` is wrong. It does not work this way in C. My proposition for that is to use logical and statement (`&&`) by writing:

```c
if (1 <= n && n <= 100000)
```

You try to limit the loop to `n` in line: `for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)` but you should have `<` sign instead of `<=`. Try to use: `for (int i=0; i<n; i++)` to limit it to `n`.

Additionally, When you are limitting it to `n` then you should not use `arr[i+1]` or `arr[i+2]`, because you are accessing values out of the array bounds (from memory which is just after the array). This is a reason of that exception. If you have some non-zero trash, then most probably your code will not have a floating point exception. Because you are using `arr[i+1]` and `arr[i+2]` in modulo operation and in some way they could be zero, then according to standard you can have the undefined behavior.

Try to use (according to your code; I do not know a purpose of it):

```c
long long good_triplets(int *arr, int n) {
  int count = 0;
  if (3 <= n && n <= 100000) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (n - 2); i++) {
      if ((((arr[i] + arr[i + 1] + arr[i + 2]) % arr[i]) == 0) &&
          (((arr[i] + arr[i + 1] + arr[i + 2]) % arr[i + 1]) != 0) &&
          (((arr[i] + arr[i + 1] + arr[i + 2]) % arr[i + 2]) != 0))
        count = count + 6;
      if ((((arr[i] + arr[i + 1] + arr[i + 2]) % arr[i + 1]) == 0) &&
          (((arr[i] + arr[i + 1] + arr[i + 2]) % arr[i]) != 0) &&
          (((arr[i] + arr[i + 1] + arr[i + 2]) % arr[i + 2]) != 0))
        count = count + 6;
      if ((((arr[i] + arr[i + 1] + arr[i + 2]) % arr[i + 2]) == 0) &&
          (((arr[i] + arr[i + 1] + arr[i + 2]) % arr[i + 1]) != 0) &&
          (((arr[i] + arr[i + 1] + arr[i + 2]) % arr[i]) != 0))
        count = count + 6;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: May I recommend to write a few words in prose, it will help with understanding the numbered list of facts which consists of one simple and one very complex sentence.

Comment: Will you are right with what you state, you probably need to explain how this might cause a floating point exception, because it looks more prone to cause segfaults instead.

Comment: @Yunnosch I can explain it, it is not a problem. But if i understand it correctly author has got a recrutation task on EarthQuake service and look for our answer...

Comment: I see. I think you might like to use this link as background for the reasoning behind your answer. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions If I am right (trying not to second guess you) and you explain within the answer, then I think it might make a lot of sense to me. ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch somhow I answered. Thank you!